# Popup box is not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my button which i have it in my jsp page

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="offerPhoneButton" onclick="offerPhone()">Offer Phone</button>
```

this is my script

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
function offerPhone() {
    var phoneDialog = $("#myPhoneList").dialog({
        title: 'My Phone',
        autoOpen : false,
        closeText : 'hide',
        show : "fade",
        hide : "fade",
        modal : true,
        width : "400px",
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left top", of: window },
        open : function() {
            alert('hi');
            // load doctor_phones.jsp into the phones dialog.

             /* $(this).load('pages/doctor/write_prescription.jsp?patient_id=' + patientId + '&patient_name=' + patientName);  
               this doesn't work, seems to return before the content is actually loaded.    */

              var content =   ajaxGetJQuery("pages/doctor/doctor_phones.jsp"); 
               $("#myPhoneList").dialog("option", "title", "My Phones"); // this is necessary, b/c the title attribute doesn't work.
              $(this).html(content);                 
        }
    });

    $("#myPhoneList").dialog("open");
}
        </script>
```

But when i click offer phone button the popup box is not getting displayed if u can find any problem with my script pls let me know

Comment: Check console for errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no problem your code. if you use

```
onclick="offerPhone()
```

your code must be between body tags like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/u0L94rLe/

Comment: Missed a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine as shown in

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/36Lcgevq/3/)

**JS**

```
function offerPhone() {
    var phoneDialog = $("#myPhoneList").dialog({
        title: 'My Phone',
        autoOpen : false,
        closeText : 'hide',
        show : "fade",
        hide : "fade",
        modal : true,
        width : "400px",
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left top", of: window },
        open : function() {
            alert('hi');
            var content =   ajaxGetJQuery("pages/doctor/doctor_phones.jsp"); 
               $("#myPhoneList").dialog("option", "title", "My Phones"); // this is necessary, b/c the title attribute doesn't work.
              $(this).html(content);                 
        }
    });




    $("#myPhoneList").dialog("open");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="offerPhoneButton" onclick="offerPhone()">Offer Phone</button>

  <div id="myPhoneList" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Heading</p>
</div>
```